# Finding issue in getting latitude and longitude

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, latitude-longitude

Here is the program I used to code it in my android application to find the GPS location of the device.

```
package com.gps.TestingApps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestingApps extends Activity implements LocationListener{
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private TextView latitude;
    private TextView longitude;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

      //bind the ui components to code referances
        latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude);
        longitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude);
      //get the locationManager
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        startListening();
    }
    private void startListening() {
         //registers our class as the listener
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) this);
    }
    private void stopListening() {
        locationManager.removeUpdates((LocationListener) this);
    }
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                latitude.setText(location.getLatitude()+"");
                longitude.setText(location.getLongitude()+"");
                stopListening();
            }
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
  }
```

I didn't get any bugs but there is a runtime error, I can't get the values of latitude and longitude instead I get the value false values for both.

here is the error message displayed in my Logcat.

```
09-04 12:52:47.541: WARN/ResourceType(59): Failure getting entry for 0x7f020000 (t=1 e=0) in package 0: 0xffffffb5
09-04 12:52:49.981: WARN/ResourceType(122): Failure getting entry for 0x7f020000 (t=1 e=0) in package 0: 0xffffffb5
09-04 12:52:50.161: WARN/PackageManager(122): Failure retrieving icon 0x7f020000 in package com.greatinnovus.TestingApps
09-04 12:52:50.161: WARN/PackageManager(122): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020000
09-04 12:52:50.161: WARN/PackageManager(122):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:846)
09-04 12:52:50.161: WARN/PackageManager(122):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:534)
09-04 12:52:50.161: WARN/PackageManager(122):     at android.app.ApplicationContext$ApplicationPackageManager.getDrawable(ApplicationContext.java:1923)
09-04 12:52:50.161: WARN/PackageManager(122):     at android.content.pm.ComponentInfo.loadIcon(ComponentInfo.java:88)
09-04 12:52:50.161: WARN/PackageManager(122):     at com.htc.launcher.LauncherModel.updateApplicationInfoTitleAndIcon(LauncherModel.java:488)
09-04 12:52:50.161: WARN/PackageManager(122):     at com.htc.launcher.LauncherModel.makeAndCacheApplicationInfo(LauncherModel.java:469)
09-04 12:52:50.161: WARN/PackageManager(122):     at com.htc.launcher.LauncherModel.access$300(LauncherModel.java:55)
09-04 12:52:50.161: WARN/PackageManager(122):     at com.htc.launcher.LauncherModel$1.run(LauncherModel.java:188)
09-04 12:52:50.181: ERROR/PackageInstallationReceiver(235): Remove /data/local/tmp/com.greatinnovus.TestingApps.apk Fail!
09-04 12:52:50.201: WARN/System.err(235): java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Commands: [/system/xbin/su, 0, /system/bin/rm, /data/local/tmp/com.greatinnovus.TestingApps.apk] Working Directory: null Environment: null
09-04 12:52:50.281: WARN/System.err(235):     at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:196)
09-04 12:52:50.291: WARN/System.err(235):     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:225)
09-04 12:52:50.291: WARN/System.err(235):     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:313)
09-04 12:52:50.301: WARN/System.err(235):     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:246)
09-04 12:52:50.301: WARN/System.err(235):     at com.htc.android.psclient.PackageInstallationReceiver.removeTempPackageFile(PackageInstallationReceiver.java:30)
09-04 12:52:50.311: WARN/System.err(235):     at com.htc.android.psclient.PackageInstallationReceiver.onReceive(PackageInstallationReceiver.java:22)
09-04 12:52:50.311: WARN/System.err(235):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2408)
09-04 12:52:50.321: WARN/System.err(235):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2700(ActivityThread.java:112)
09-04 12:52:50.321: WARN/System.err(235):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1741)
09-04 12:52:50.321: WARN/System.err(235):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-04 12:52:50.331: WARN/System.err(235):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-04 12:52:50.331: WARN/System.err(235):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
09-04 12:52:50.341: WARN/System.err(235):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-04 12:52:50.351: WARN/System.err(235):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-04 12:52:50.351: WARN/System.err(235):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
09-04 12:52:50.351: WARN/System.err(235):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
09-04 12:52:50.361: WARN/System.err(235):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-04 12:52:50.361: WARN/System.err(235): Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
09-04 12:52:50.381: WARN/System.err(235):     at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method)
09-04 12:52:50.391: WARN/System.err(235):     at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:194)
09-04 12:52:50.391: WARN/System.err(235):     ... 16 more
09-04 12:52:51.751: WARN/Resources(1707): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f050000}
09-04 12:52:51.751: WARN/Resources(1707): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f050002}
09-04 12:53:19.541: ERROR/SETTING_AUTO_BACKLIGHT(59): open: /sys/class/leds/lcd-backlight/auto failed, errno: 2
09-04 12:54:27.811: ERROR/SETTING_AUTO_BACKLIGHT(59): open: /sys/class/leds/lcd-backlight/auto failed, errno: 2
09-04 12:54:43.911: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(1707): Bad keycharmap - filesize=32
09-04 12:54:45.313: WARN/WeatherUtil(122): schedule DCS task, mixed quest code
09-04 12:54:51.962: WARN/MobileDataStateTracker(59): startUsingNetworkFeature=enableAGPS  callid=59calluid= 1000
09-04 12:55:21.951: WARN/MobileDataStateTracker(59): stopUsingNetworkFeature=enableAGPS  callid=59calluid= 1000
09-04 12:55:38.811: WARN/dalvikvm(122): disableGcForExternalAlloc: true
09-04 12:55:38.971: ERROR/SETTING_AUTO_BACKLIGHT(59): open: /sys/class/leds/lcd-backlight/auto failed, errno: 2
09-04 12:55:39.661: WARN/dalvikvm(122): disableGcForExternalAlloc: false
09-04 12:55:39.841: WARN/dalvikvm(122): disableGcForExternalAlloc: true
09-04 12:55:40.981: WARN/dalvikvm(122): disableGcForExternalAlloc: false
09-04 12:55:43.481: WARN/WeatherUtil(122): schedule DCS task, mixed quest code
09-04 12:56:26.191: WARN/dalvikvm(122): disableGcForExternalAlloc: true
09-04 12:56:27.301: WARN/dalvikvm(122): disableGcForExternalAlloc: false
09-04 12:56:29.811: WARN/WeatherUtil(122): schedule DCS task, mixed quest code
09-04 12:56:42.331: WARN/ResourceType(59): Failure getting entry for 0x7f020000 (t=1 e=0) in package 0: 0xffffffb5
09-04 12:56:45.691: ERROR/PackageInstallationReceiver(235): Remove /data/local/tmp/com.greatinnovus.TestingApps.apk Fail!
09-04 12:56:45.711: WARN/System.err(235): java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Commands: [/system/xbin/su, 0, /system/bin/rm, /data/local/tmp/com.greatinnovus.TestingApps.apk] Working Directory: null Environment: null
09-04 12:56:45.711: WARN/System.err(235):     at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:196)
09-04 12:56:45.711: WARN/System.err(235):     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:225)
09-04 12:56:45.711: WARN/System.err(235):     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:313)
09-04 12:56:45.721: WARN/System.err(235):     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:246)
09-04 12:56:45.721: WARN/System.err(235):     at com.htc.android.psclient.PackageInstallationReceiver.removeTempPackageFile(PackageInstallationReceiver.java:30)
09-04 12:56:45.721: WARN/System.err(235):     at com.htc.android.psclient.PackageInstallationReceiver.onReceive(PackageInstallationReceiver.java:22)
09-04 12:56:45.721: WARN/System.err(235):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2408)
09-04 12:56:45.721: WARN/System.err(235):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2700(ActivityThread.java:112)
09-04 12:56:45.721: WARN/System.err(235):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1741)
09-04 12:56:45.721: WARN/System.err(235):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-04 12:56:45.731: WARN/System.err(235):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-04 12:56:45.731: WARN/System.err(235):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
09-04 12:56:45.731: WARN/System.err(235):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-04 12:56:45.731: WARN/System.err(235):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-04 12:56:45.741: WARN/System.err(235):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
09-04 12:56:45.741: WARN/System.err(235):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
09-04 12:56:45.741: WARN/System.err(235):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-04 12:56:45.741: WARN/System.err(235): Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
09-04 12:56:45.761: WARN/System.err(235):     at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method)
09-04 12:56:45.761: WARN/System.err(235):     at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:194)
09-04 12:56:45.761: WARN/System.err(235):     ... 16 more
09-04 12:56:45.901: WARN/ResourceType(122): Failure getting entry for 0x7f020000 (t=1 e=0) in package 0: 0xffffffb5
09-04 12:56:45.941: WARN/PackageManager(122): Failure retrieving icon 0x7f020000 in package com.greatinnovus.TestingApps
09-04 12:56:45.941: WARN/PackageManager(122): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020000
09-04 12:56:45.941: WARN/PackageManager(122):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:846)
09-04 12:56:45.941: WARN/PackageManager(122):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:534)
09-04 12:56:45.941: WARN/PackageManager(122):     at android.app.ApplicationContext$ApplicationPackageManager.getDrawable(ApplicationContext.java:1923)
09-04 12:56:45.941: WARN/PackageManager(122):     at android.content.pm.ComponentInfo.loadIcon(ComponentInfo.java:88)
09-04 12:56:45.941: WARN/PackageManager(122):     at com.htc.launcher.LauncherModel.updateApplicationInfoTitleAndIcon(LauncherModel.java:488)
09-04 12:56:45.941: WARN/PackageManager(122):     at com.htc.launcher.LauncherModel.updateAndCacheApplicationInfo(LauncherModel.java:289)
09-04 12:56:45.941: WARN/PackageManager(122):     at com.htc.launcher.LauncherModel.access$500(LauncherModel.java:55)
09-04 12:56:45.941: WARN/PackageManager(122):     at com.htc.launcher.LauncherModel$2.run(LauncherModel.java:265)
09-04 12:56:46.551: WARN/Resources(1751): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f050000}
09-04 12:56:46.551: WARN/Resources(1751): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f050002}
09-04 12:56:59.111: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(1751): Bad keycharmap - filesize=32
09-04 12:57:00.524: WARN/WeatherUtil(122): schedule DCS task, mixed quest code
09-04 12:57:59.821: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 12:58:59.911: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 12:59:59.981: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:01:00.121: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:01:03.131: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:01:06.141: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:02:06.281: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:03:06.461: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:03:09.463: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:03:12.481: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:04:12.621: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:05:12.741: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:05:15.744: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:05:18.751: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:06:18.881: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:06:21.873: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:07:21.963: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:07:24.971: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:07:27.981: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:08:28.181: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:08:31.182: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:08:34.201: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:08:37.221: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:08:40.241: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:09:40.383: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:09:43.381: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:09:46.401: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:10:46.531: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:11:46.641: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:11:49.641: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:12:49.771: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:12:52.771: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:12:55.801: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:12:58.822: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:12:59.721: WARN/Smack/Packet(166): notify conn break (IOEx), close connection
09-04 13:13:01.832: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:13:04.842: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
09-04 13:13:07.861: WARN/LocationManagerService(59): acquireWakeLock(): Unable to get WiFi lock
```

Comment: Would you please try to edit your question and manually indent each code and log line so it can be read? Would help us quite a lot.

Comment: Dumping logs here isn't going to help much.  Explain your problem clearly.

Comment: Please format your question properly, it looks really messy. And use pastebin.com to post long logfiles, or only post the relevant parts of it here.

Comment: That logfile is a lot to scroll through, and it repeats a lot at the end.  You should use pastebin.com, like Mathias Lin said.

Comment: sure Hope to follow, sorry to make a mess here.Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not related to GPS in any way. You're simply missing an icon in your res/drawable folder, that you're referencing to from somewhere, as you can see in your log.

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:
>   Resource ID #0x7f020000 09-0

Comment: sure, Hope to follow, sorry to make a mess here.Thanks for your suggestions Mathias